# For loop logic to skip processing files

Tags: command-line, bash, cygwin, bash-scripting

I wrote the following script in an attempt to try my hand at automation, to automate some common transformations on sets of text files I work with:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e

if [ $# -eq 0 ]; then
echo "USAGE: $0 FILE"
echo "USAGE: Pass a colon-delimited text file as input."
exit
else               
    for i; do
      echo "Checking file \"$i\" is colon-delimited..." &&
        head "$i" | while IFS= read -r line; do 
        if [[ " $line " =~ ':' ]]; then continue;
        else 
            echo "Input \"$i\" is not colon-delimited. Leaving file."
            continue 2
        fi
        done        

        echo "Transforming file \"$i\"..." &&
        awk -F: '$1!="" && $2!=""' "$i" |                 # Filter out lines with empty columns
        awk -F: '{gsub(/ /, "", $1); print $1 FS $2}' |   # Remove all spaces in first column; assumes two columns delimited by ':'
        grep -aE ":|@" |                                  # Filter out lines that don't contain '@' or ':'
        tr -d '\000-\011\013-\037' |                      # Remove all control characters apart from (Linux) newline
        awk 'length >=7 && length <=150' |                # Filter out very short and long lines
        LC_ALL=C sort -u > "${i%_final.*}" #&&            # Sort and deduplicate
    done
fi
```

### Expected behaviour

Take files as input, or exit if no input is given. Read the first 10 lines of each input file to check whether it contains a colon. If it does, apply the transformations to the file; if even one of the lines doesn't contain a colon, skip the file and start processing the next one.

### Actual behaviour

Most of the script works; it exits if no input is given, and successfully determines whether a file is colon-delimited or not.

The problem is confined to the `for` loop: no matter how many variations of `break` and `continue` I try, they all ultimately end in the same result - all of the files are transformed whether they're colon-delimited or not.

Running the script through `bash -n` and [ShellCheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) shows no issues.

All of this points to a stupidly simple logic problem, but I've been looking at it for days and still been unable to express my logic into code.

This is the output I get when I run the command:

```
$ time ../transform_files.sh *
Checking file "file1" is colon-delimited...
Transforming file "file1"...
awk: cmd. line:1: (FILENAME=- FNR=4) warning: Invalid multibyte data detected. There may be a mismatch between your data and your locale.
Checking file "file2.sh" is colon-delimited...
Input "file2.sh" is not colon-delimited. Leaving file.
Transforming file "file2.sh"...
Checking file "file3.in.txt" is colon-delimited...
Transforming file "file3.in.txt"...
awk: cmd. line:1: (FILENAME=- FNR=44) warning: Invalid multibyte data detected. There may be a mismatch between your data and your locale.
Checking file "file4.txt" is colon-delimited...
Input "file4.txt" is not colon-delimited. Leaving file.
Transforming file "file4.txt"...

real    0m4.375s
user    0m0.349s
sys     0m0.805s
```

*N.B. I'm aware the `awk` errors can be fixed with `LC_ALL=C`, but my input files tend to contain a lot of non-ASCII characters that can't be discarded.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The logic itself is not bad, I guess. The problem is `continue` can only affect the flow of the shell that executes it.

Bash runs the right-hand side of a pipeline in a subshell context. The relevant fragment of your code is a pipeline; `continue 2` is in a subshell:

```bsh
head "$i" | while …
   …
   continue 2
   …
done
```

That's why it cannot affect the flow of your `for` loop which is *outside* the subshell.

People usually discover this behavior of Bash when [`read` "doesn't work"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/143958/108618). For you it's `continue 2` that "doesn't work" but the reason is the same. So are solutions:

- Run `while …` not in a pipe:

  ```
   while … done < <(head "$i")
  ```
- Or tell Bash to change its behavior. Tell it to run the last command of a pipeline in the current shell environment:

  ```
   # before the troublesome pipeline
   shopt -s lastpipe
  ```

Comment: Glad to know that my logic was good, that was frustrating me to no end. The process substitution solution works perfectly, I'll need to keep in mind this gotcha about pipes for the future.